# How to remove XML entity references in Actionscript

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I need to remove a bunch of `&apos;` from a string that I obtained through an XML document. I'm working with Actionscript 2, so Regex is not an option for me. Even though I'm looking for an Actionscript 2 solution, still reply with an Actionscript 3 answer if you have one for anyone else who might need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a simple [string search and replace](http://www.webtoolkit.info/actionscript-string-replace.html)?